# How to get two turtles in a single turtlesimnode

Tags: ros2

Create a simple controller for turtlesim using python and use it to perform the desired maneuver with 2 turtles exactly as described below.

There are three things that need to be done:

First, draw a circle with the first turtle.

When the first circle is drawn, the controller node must stop the first turtle and call a service to spawn another turtle.

Lastly, the second turtle should draw another circle bigger than the previous one and stop when it is drawn.

I am expexting a code / idea / some reference to know about two turtles usage in a single turtlesim node like this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.